# Protected method error with explicit receiver (Ruby 1.9.3)

Tags: ruby

In ruby 1.9.3, why does `Foo.explicit_receiver` produce a "protected method called" error?

I am referencing these tutorials:

- [Protected Methods and Ruby 2.0](http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/09/07/protected-methods-and-ruby-2-0.html)
- [Ruby Access Control – Are Private And Protected Methods Only A Guideline?](http://www.skorks.com/2010/04/ruby-access-control-are-private-and-protected-methods-only-a-guideline/)

Which state:

> You can always call a protected method with an implicit receiver, just
>   like private, but in addition you can call a protected method with an
>   explicit receiver as long as this receiver is self or an object of the
>   same class as self.

I am calling the protected with a `Foo` instance, which should allow me to call the protected method. I'm definitely missing something :)

**Code Example**

```
class Foo
  def implicit_receiver
    protected_method
  end

  def explicit_receiver
    self.protected_method
  end

  def self.explicit_receiver
    Foo.new.tap do |foo|
      foo.protected_method
    end
  end

protected

  def protected_method
    p "called protected method!"
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.implicit_receiver
foo.explicit_receiver
Foo.explicit_receiver

# output
# "called protected method!"
# "called protected method!"
# protected.rb:12:in `explicit_receiver': protected method `protected_method' called for #<Foo:0x10a280978> (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: (Ignore, can't delete on mobile client-will remove later.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Protected methods are available to instance methods of other instances of the same class or subclass.  However, the `explicit_receiver` that is throwing the error is a singleton method of the class (actually the metaclass) itself and does not have access to the class's protected instance methods.

You can see this by simply running:

```
class Foo
  def self.test
    Foo.new.protected_method
  end
end

Foo.test
```

You'll get a similar error.

What makes it confusing in this case is that you are calling `tap` on the instance you created and still get this error.  This is because the binding for the `tap` block is still in the context of the metaclass that can't access the protected instance methods of its class - you can check `self` inside that block to see this.

Comment: So what you're saying is the `self.explicit_receiver` is defined on the "eigenclass" thus it doesn't have access to the `Foo`s protected members?

Comment: Yes.  The simply stated reason is that the metaclass is a subclass of Class, not of Foo.